# Como fazer a função date() formatar uma data em português?

Tags: php, data

No meu projeto estou a usar a função `date()`, no entanto gostaria que fosse em português, a saída da data de momento é: `Thursday 6th`, gostaria que ficasse no mesmo modelo mas em português, este é o meu código:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
echo date('l jS'); // Thursday 6th
```

Answer (score 177, accepted):

**Abordagem com strftime**

Use [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php) para criar a data por extenso, pois essa função pega automaticamente o locale. Como citado pelo @bfavaretto, basta informar o locale.

`strftime()` nas palavras do manual:

> Formata uma hora/data local de acordo com o configuração de locale.
>   Nome do mês e dia da semana e outras strings dependem do atual local
>   definido com setlocale().

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today'));
```

saida:

```
quinta-feira, 06 de março de 2014
```

%A: dia da semana por extenso.

%d: dia do mês representado com dois digitos.

%B: mês por extenso.

%Y: ano representado com quatro digitos.

**[Exemplo - strftime](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t2s0-cnj3)**

---

**Abordagem com IntlDateFormatter**

É possivel também obter o mesmo resultado com as classes [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) e [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php). Importante a biblioteca INTL deve estar habilitada.

Os formatos de data e hora são:

```
Data
Constante  |Saida
FULL       |segunda-feira, 1 de setembro de 2014
TRADITIONAL|segunda-feira, 1 de setembro de 2014
LONG       |1 de setembro de 2014
MEDIUM     |01/09/2014
SHORT      |01/09/14
NONE       |

Hora
Constante  |Saida
FULL       |03h00min00s GMT+00:00
TRADITIONAL|03h00min00s GMT+00:00
LONG       |03h00min00s GMT+00:00
MEDIUM     |03:00:00
SHORT      |03:00
NONE       |
```

**[Exemplo - formato data/hora](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6vee-4hvf)**

No construtor é necessario informar quatro argumentos: locale, formato da data, formato da hora, timezone e o tipo de calendario

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$data = new DateTime();
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('pt_BR',
                                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
                                    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
                                    'America/Sao_Paulo',          
                                    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
echo $formatter->format($data);
```

**[Exemplo - IntlDateFormatter](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dffw-4dpe)**

Para uma saida personalizada use o método `setPattern()` e especifique o formato conforme a [documentação](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

**Relacionda:**

[Usar o setlocale apenas para a date](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210572/91)

Comment: @Miguel Formate o mês em separado, use a função ucfirst nele e então junte tudo no final.

Comment: @Miguel vc pode usar `ucwords` para deixar toda inicial em maiuscula. `$data = strftime( '%A, %d  %B  %Y', strtotime('today'));
echo ucwords($data);`

Comment: @Miguel vc deve pegar o retorno de `strftime()` e jogar numa variável e só no `echo` usar `ucfirst` como está no outro comentário.

Comment: :) Muito obrigado @rray. Foi muito util sua resposta, já estava quase criando um plugin para fazer das nestes formatos em portugues.

Comment: Melhor resposta de todas

Comment: Os parâmetros da Classe são : locale, datetype , timetype, ***timezone***, calendar, pattern. Da forma que está não vai funcionar, pois falta o **timezone** (ex: `'America/Sao_Paulo'`) antes do **calendar** `IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN`

Comment: Ótima resposta! Para quem já tem o objeto DateTime: `echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', $dateTimeObject->getTimestamp());`

Comment: Você citou 'pt_BR.utf-8' duas vezes nos argumentos da função setlocale(), tá correto isso ou foi um erro de digitação? Curiosidade apenas...

Comment: A partir do PHP 8.1 a função `strftime` foi depreciada: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 31):

Alterando o local do PHP você pode adquirir as propriedades de determinado país. Para alterar estas propriedades usaremos a função `setlocale()`.

Em servidores configurados em formato brasileiro, ou seja, que já tem `Brazilian Portuguese` configurado no `locale`, apenas `setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);` seria suficiente.
Em servidores estrangeiros, talvez apenas `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');` seria suficiente. Para aumentar a compatibilidade experimente utilizar os dois em  conjunto:

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');  
    print ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A'));
?>
```

A função utilizada para puxar os dados da data é a `gmstrftime()` porque ela leva em consideração o local.
O retorno desta função é o dia da semana, por extenso, em português! :)

`LC_ALL` é uma constante que indica que as informações locais serão definidas em todas as instâncias. `LC_ALL` engloba `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_MONETARY`, `LC_NUMERIC` e `LC_TIME`.

Comment: Isso está correto, a minha sugestão com `date` não estava (a função não é afetada pelo `setlocale`). Infelizmente acabaram meus votos por hoje, não posso votar nesta resposta agora.

Comment: sem problemas, se a resposta for útil ao @miguel pra mim já é o suficiente

Comment: Muito Obgado... resultou @Erlon

Answer (score 24):

Se nenhuma das outras respostas funcionar, pode ser que o locales pt-br não esteja instalado no servidor (que foi o meu problema). Neste caso, se seu servidor é Linux Ubuntu, você precisa executar:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-pt 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Este era o meu problema. Por via das dúvidas na hora de configurar o locales eu botei para permitir todos, assim dependendo da aplicação no server eu mudo para a necessária.

Answer (score 19):

Use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$var_DateTime = SUA DATA DO BANCO //No meu caso tipo ISO do mongoDB... aí uso o "->sec"

// Caso não queira letras maiúsculas no início de algumas palavras, pode ser usado apenas assim:
echo utf8_encode(strftime('%A, %d, de %B de %Y', $var_DateTime->sec))

//utf8_encode para tratar os caracteres especiais, caso precise
//ucwords para colocar a primeira letra maiúscula

echo utf8_encode(ucwords(strftime('%A', $var_DateTime->sec)).', '.strftime('%d', $var_DateTime->sec).' de '.ucwords(strftime('%B', $var_DateTime->sec)).' de '.strftime('%Y', $var_DateTime->sec));
```

Resutado:

```
quinta-feira, 21 de dezembro de 2013
Quinta-feira, 21 de Dezembro de 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Com o PHP 7.0 ou mais novo o recomendável é usar DateTime com IntlDateFormatter

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$suaData = '2022-10-13';
$dateTime = new DateTime($suaData);
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
     'pt_BR'
     ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL
     ,IntlDateFormatter::NONE
     ,'America/Sao_Paulo'       
     ,IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
     ,"dd 'de' MMMM 'de' YYYY"
   );
$retorno = $formatter->format($dateTime);
echo '<br>'.$retorno;
```

Retorno esperado 12 de outubro de 2022

Agradecimento especial Matheus Battisti no atigo dele que me deu um norte
https://www.horadecodar.com.br/2020/05/09/como-fazer-data-em-portugues-no-php-funcao-date/