# Converter número do mês para o nome

Tags: php, datetime, data

Eu preciso converter o número do mês para o nome do mesmo, mas tem que ser em português (e de preferência sem a necessidade de `substr`)

Eu consigo fazer isso, com a linguagem padrão em Inglês

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F');
echo substr($monthName, 0, 3);
// output Mar
```

[teste online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d081dbf98dd3e4e8c401a784fc3a8c2e98686a8)

Há um modo de modificar o tipo de linguagem para pt-Br para utilizar essa função?

---

Eu não quero criar um `array()` contendo todos os meses já abreviados e em português. Quero uma solução `in-built`

Comment: Talvez ajude, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: Desculpe, é a primeira vez que crio uma pergunta nesse SE. Se eu fiz errado, favor, coloque um comentário para eu poder corrigir, somente vote negativamente não ajuda a melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: @perdeu talvez ajude, procurei no site antes de criar a pergunta e não achei nada. Eu estava procurando por algo diretamente relacionado ao título que eu criei.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Com a ajuda do [comentário do @perdeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21635/converter-n%C3%BAmero-do-m%C3%AAs-para-o-nome#comment39133_21635) aonde ele indica a questão [Como fazer a função date() formatar uma data em português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs) eu fiz as seguintes modificações para acessar a data que eu necessito (note que o [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) é um pouco diferente do proposto na pergunta, mas é o que eu preciso)

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' );
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );

echo strftime('%h', strtotime("-3 months"));
```

[Teste online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82aa961bc8b8fd2feb3b7a45e0b4448e98c086f5)

Answer (score 7):

Apesar de já haver uma resposta, fica a ressalva de que com relação à localização, a classe [DateTime](http://ww.php.net/class.datetime) é avoada e não presta atenção àquilo que foi definido, sendo mesmo necessário usar [strftime()](http://www.php.net/strftime)

No seu caso, para retornar a representação textual **completa** ficaria assim:

```
strftime( '%B', $dateObj -> getTimestamp() );
```

Destaquei o termo **completa** pois você usa um [substr()](http://www.php.net/substr) para encurtar a saída. Nesse caso, seria mais interessante usar:

```
strftime( '%b', $dateObj -> getTimestamp() );
```

E obter a representação abreviada correta.

Comment: +1 muito bom o ponto. É bem importante esse fato.

Answer (score 7):

Sei que faz tempo que foi perguntado, e tem soluções baseadas em locales, mas como uma 2º opção, gostaria de colocar esta abordagem, como exemplo de solução sem testes lógicos.

Acho uma má prática aninhar `if`'s como se não houvesse amanhã.

A partir disto, pode montar classe, função, fuso, etc... A idéia é exemplificar como fazer a mesma coisa, sem usar testes lógicos aninhados, ou `switch`'s enormes.

```
    $numero_dia = date('w')*1;
    $dia_mes = date('d');
    $numero_mes = date('m')*1;
    $ano = date('Y');
    $dia = array('Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado');
    $mes = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');
    echo $dia[$numero_dia] . ", " .$dia_mes . " de " . $mes[$numero_mes] . " de " . $ano . ".";
```

Saída: Sexta-feira, 25 de Setembro de 2014.

Answer (score 4):

As respostas já presentes são o caminho a seguir, mas para quem está com problemas a definir o `locale` para Português, cenário por vezes impossível ou limitado devido às definições do servidor, fica uma função que não se baseia nas definições fornecidas pelo `setlocale`, fazendo sim uma verificação do valores recebidos e devolvendo a data formatada em Português:

### Função em PHP

```
/**
 * Converter TimeStamp para data em Português
 *
 * @param integer $timestamp Unix timestamp
 * @param boolean $hours Se "true" devolve também as horas
 * @param string $timeZone Zona a utilizar para gerar as horas
 *
 * @return string
 */
function dataEmPortugues ($timestamp, $hours = FALSE, $timeZone = "Europe/Lisbon") {

    $dia_num = date("w", $timestamp);// Dia da semana.

    if($dia_num == 0){
    $dia_nome = "Domingo";
    }elseif($dia_num == 1){
    $dia_nome = "Segunda";
    }elseif($dia_num == 2){
    $dia_nome = "Terça";
    }elseif($dia_num == 3){
    $dia_nome = "Quarta";
    }elseif($dia_num == 4){
    $dia_nome = "Quinta";
    }elseif($dia_num == 5){
    $dia_nome = "Sexta";
    }else{
    $dia_nome = "Sábado";
    }

    $dia_mes = date("d", $timestamp);// Dia do mês

    $mes_num = date("m", $timestamp);// Nome do mês

    if($mes_num == 01){
    $mes_nome = "Janeiro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 02){
    $mes_nome = "Fevereiro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 03){
    $mes_nome = "Março";
    }elseif($mes_num == 04){
    $mes_nome = "Abril";
    }elseif($mes_num == 05){
    $mes_nome = "Maio";
    }elseif($mes_num == 06){
    $mes_nome = "Junho";
    }elseif($mes_num == 07){
    $mes_nome = "Julho";
    }elseif($mes_num == 08){
    $mes_nome = "Agosto";
    }elseif($mes_num == 09){
    $mes_nome = "Setembro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 10){
    $mes_nome = "Outubro";
    }elseif($mes_num == 11){
    $mes_nome = "Novembro";
    }else{
    $mes_nome = "Dezembro";
    }
    $ano = date("Y", $timestamp);// Ano

    date_default_timezone_set($timeZone); // Set time-zone
    $hora = date ("H:i", $timestamp);

    if ($hours) {
        return $dia_nome.", ".$dia_mes." de ".$mes_nome." de ".$ano." - ".$hora;
    }
    else {
        return $dia_nome.", ".$dia_mes." de ".$mes_nome." de ".$ano;
    }
}
```

### Exemplo de utilização:

```
// data actual
echo dataEmPortugues(time());

// uma outra data
echo dataEmPortugues(strtotime("2014-07-17 21:49:23"));

// com data e hora
echo dataEmPortugues(strtotime("2014-07-17 21:49:23"), TRUE);

// com data e hora São Paulo
echo dataEmPortugues(strtotime("2014-07-17 21:49:23"), TRUE, "America/Sao_Paulo");
```

### Resultado do Exemplo

[**Ver Exemplo Online - PHP Sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/394f3c7da1de54989dd67a26209485b05ebd2833)

```
// data actual
// Terça, 17 de Junho de 2014

// uma outra data
// Quinta, 17 de Julho de 2014

// com data e hora
// Quinta, 17 de Julho de 2014 - 21:49

// com data e hora São Paulo
// Quinta, 17 de Julho de 2014 - 17:49
```

Comment: Dica, Troque o conjunto de `elseif` por `switch`. o desempenho é melhor e é mais fácil de se ler.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que vc queira algo bem resumido e simples só o básico mesmo.

Descubra o Mês

```
<form action="" method="POST"> <!--passando os parametros pelo metodo post-->
    <fieldset>
        <legend><H3>INSIRA UM NÚMERO DE 1 A 12 </H3></legend>
        <p>
            <b>MÊS:</b> <input type="text" name="pos" required><!--armazena a opção na váriavel pos -->
        </p>

        <input type="submit" name="identifica" value="Qual é o Mês ?"><!--Identificando o fomulario  no neame para mandar para o php-->

        <?php

            if (isset($_POST['identifica'])) {  /* validando os campos se estão preechidos pelo isset que retorna true e recebe os paramentros 
                do formulario pelo identifica e seu respectivo método post*/
            }   

            $pos = intval($_POST["pos"]);   //declarando a váriavel pos erecebendo o valor inteiro pelo intval

            if (($pos >= 13)||($pos <=0)){// validando se o usuário digitou valores válidos
                echo "<br><br><b>Não digite letras!<br>E valores somente de 1 a 12.</b>";

            }else{

                $mes = array("","Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto",
                "Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro");

                    echo "<br><br><b>Você escolheu ".$mes[$pos]."</b>";// retornando o mes do ano no array de acordo com a posição que foi inserida no formulário 
                    // e armazenada na váriavel $pos
            }

        ?>
        <!--fim do programa-->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Há outra maneira. Seu servidor precisa suportar configurar o locale em pt_BR:

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $monthNum);
$dateObj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$monthName = $dateObj->format('M');
echo $monthName;
```

[Veja funcionando](https://ideone.com/F8lR2y)

Answer (score -3):

Uma outra alternativa com case:

```
public function nome_mes($mes_e)
{ 
   switch ($mes_e) {
        case 1:$mes_s='JAN';break;case 2:$mes_s='FEV';break;case 3:$mes_s='MAR';break;case 4:$mes_s='ABR';break;case 5:$mes_s='MAI';break;case 6:$mes_s='JUN';break;
        case 7:$mes_s='JUL';break;case 8:$mes_s='AGO';break;case 9:$mes_s='SET';break;case 10:$mes_s='OUT';break;case 11:$mes_s='NOV';break;case 12:$mes_s='DEZ';break;
    };
    return $mes_s;
}
```