# Pegar o nome do mês caso o dia do evento seja no mês seguinte

Tags: php

Tenho um site onde mostra o dia do evento que ocorre todas as quintas-feiras. Para isso, fiz dessa forma:

```
<?php
$data = date("w");
if($data == 4)
{
    echo "hoje";
}
else
{
    echo date('d', strtotime("next Thursday"));
}
?>
```

E como resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que estamos no dia 28/07 e o próximo evento cai em agosto. Como eu faria para que, caso o evento seja em um dia que caia no mês seguinte, ele mostre automaticamente, caso contrário ele mostre o mês atual?

Comment: Cite mais exemplos!

Comment: Adicione quantos dias falta e depois diminuir pelo número dias no mês passado. Ex.: `28+4=>32-31=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá.

Você esqueceu do método: `date('m', strtotime("next Thursday")) ;`

Solução:

```php
<?php
$data = date("w");
if($data == 4)
{
    echo "hoje";
}
else
{
    $mes = array("JAN","FEV","MAR","ABR","MAI","JUN","JUL","AGO","SET","OUT","NOV","DEZ");
    echo date('d', strtotime("next Thursday")) . " " . $mes[date('m', strtotime("next Thursday")) -1];
}
?>
```

Console:

```
01 AGO
```

Fonte:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26629/152846

Eu espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito Maury. Muito obrigado!