# Formatar data no PHP

Tags: php

Preciso mostrar data no PHP no formato seguinte: "Domingo, 09 de Dezembro de 2014" ?


Tem que ser no horário de brasilia!
Se possível em português também!

**EDIT**:

```
<?php 
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' ); 
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
echo strftime( '%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today')); 
?>
```

detalhe é que o resultado é "terça-feira" e não "terça", queria saber como tirar o feira, é possível ?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: cara valew, quase fiz tudo com IF, ia ficar um código imenso...valew!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aqui deu certo.

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
print strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y");

?>
```

output

```
terça, 12 de agosto de 2014
```

Comment: valew!!! era isso que eu precisava!!

Comment: detalhe é que o resultado é "terça-feira" e não "terça", queria saber como tirar o feira, é possível ?

Comment: engraçado, aqui aparece como terça....vish

Comment: aqui aparece terça-feira!!! estou usando o xampp como servidor!

Comment: ah, nesse caso, vai na gambi - 
$str = strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y");
$str = str_replace("-feira","",$str);

Comment: deu certo! valew!!

Comment: não buga sabado e domingo? ou uso IF ?

Comment: é provável q não, mais vai ter q esperar kkk

Comment: ^^ ah, valew!!!