# Converter data MySQL (YYYY/mm/dd h:m:s) para dd/mm/aaaa

Tags: php, mysql

Vejam meu banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
<?php 
$data = $noticia->data_cadastro;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
echo strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($data));
?>
```

Conteúdo da variável: `$data`: `var_dump: "string '09/02/2015 15:55:30' (length=19)"`

Retorna no formato: "quarta-feira, 02 de setembro de 2015".

Gostaria que retornasse "segunda-feira, 09 de fevereiro de 2015"; e em seguida, personalizar para "09 Fevereiro 2015";como que faço?

Difere da postagem:"[Formatar data no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28733/formatar-data-no-php)" pois onde está `echo strftime( '%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today'));` no meu caso possui uma variável `$date`, simples, mas está fazendo diferença no meu caso.

Comment: Você quer dizer `09 de Fevereiro`?

Comment: @Oeslei, 09 de fevereiro de 2015, mas deve ser exibido como "02 Fevereiro 2015", layout...

Comment: Nunca irá exibir "02 Fevereiro 2015" se a sua data for "2015-02-09 (2015 Fevereiro 09)"

Comment: @LuisHenrique, parecido, mudando "strtotime('today'));" para "strtotime('$data'))" e não deu certo...

Comment: O tipo do campo está marcado como o quê?

Comment: Pergunta confusa! :\

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, veja se melhorou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim deverá funcionar:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$olddata = '09/02/2015 15:55:30';
$data = str_replace('/', '-', $olddata);

// Formato para por no Layout (pedido antes da edição da pergunta)
echo strftime("%m %B de %Y", strtotime($data)); // 02 fevereiro de 2015

// Como pedido após a edição da pergunta, personalizar a data para 09 de fevereiro de 2015
echo strftime("%d de %B de %Y", strtotime($data)) // 09 de fevereiro de 2015
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMY0QyQ3FkeDl1THM)</kbd>

Comment: No exemplo acima dá certo, qdo acrescenta a variável não funciona. Veja o conteúdo da $data "string '09/02/2015 15:55:30' (length=19)".

Comment: Quase, só falta retornar em pt-BR, veja como está: "02 Feb 2015".

Comment: Quando informa a variável "$data = $noticia->data_cadastro;", o formato fica "02 setembro 2015", o que pode ser?

Comment: Desse jeito dá certo: "$data = "2015-02-09 15:55:30";". Mas a variável $data recebe o resultado do método: "$data = $noticia->data_cadastro;" no seguinte formato (var_dump): "string '09/02/2015 15:55:30' (length=19)" e então fica no formato não desejado "02 setembro 2015".

Comment: Retorna "02 February 2015", me ajude a converter para pt_BR, não estou conseguindo...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21373/discussion-between-adriano-aquino-and-qmechanic73).

Comment: @AdrianoAquino Execute esse código para ver se muda algo. =D

Comment: @AdrianoAquino Se ainda não der certo me chame no [**chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21373/discussion-between-adriano-aquino-and-qmechanic73). :)

Comment: ok, pausei esta parte do projeto, rsrsrs

Comment: @AdrianoAquino Desistiu? haha, chegou ao menos a testar esse último código que postei? cheguei a instalar o PHP só para ver se isso acontecia comigo, mas não aconteceu. =D

Comment: E... tentei viu, e não virou, deve ser algum problema com minha máquina, quem sabe uma formatação no S.O. resolve... Mas vlw pela ajuda! =)

Comment: @AdrianoAquino Vish! Se possível marque alguma das respostas como aceita. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Se você quer retornar apenas `09 Fevereiro 2015`, então faça da seguinte forma:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");

echo strftime("%d %B %Y", strtotime($data));
```

No seu exemplo, parece haver um erro de interpretação entre `mm` e `dd`, e vice-versa.

Nesse caso, essa solução abaixo funcionaria, mas ainda recomendo que você identifique se há algum erro de formatação da data causada por regionalização da mesma.

```
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/yy', $noticia->data_cadastro)->getTimestamp();

echo strftime("%d %B %Y", $data);
```

Veja que criamos a data a partir do formato `m/d/yy`, e não como `d/m/yy`, por causa da formatação da sua data.

## Atualização

Porém, se você quer fazer exatamente como está no título da pergunta, que é *"Converter data MySQL (YYYY/mm/dd h:m:s) para dd/mm/aaaa"*, então você pode fazer assim.

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('yy/m/d H:i:s', $data)->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Ainda retorna "02 setembro 2015"

Comment: @AdrianoAquino deves ter outro problema então, veja funcionando no https://ideone.com/5C4Ifs

Comment: @AdrianoAquino Talvez você salvou a data errada no banco. Verifique diretamente no banco a data salva.

Comment: Nesse caso por ser problema de formato. Talvez um `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/yy', $data)->getTimestamp()`. Pois vejo que ele interpreta o `dd` como `mm` e o `mm` como `dd`.

Comment: @Oeslei, veja o print do BD...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que ele quer retornar: Mês em número decimal + Nome do Mês + Ano. Isso que entendi.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, está correto, mas veja o conteúdo da variável: "string '09/02/2015 15:55:30' (length=19)".

Comment: Como assim, @AdrianoAquino? Você não postou nada na sua pergunta com esse formato? Isso induziu a minha resposta da forma que foi colocada. Se existe um `var_dump` com esse resultado, favor informar na sua pergunta. Assim, talvez eu possa completar minha resposta da maneira mais adequada ao seu problema.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, não tinha pensado em usar um var_dump anterioemente, estou iniciando em PHP, tinha focado somente no BD... sinto muito.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso diretamente na query mysql

Usando o [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)

Exemplo

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(data_cadastro,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data_formatada FROM sua_tabela
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se funciona no `MYSQL`, mas no `PostgreSQL` seria equivalente a

```
to_char(data_cadastro, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```