# Comparação de datas PHP - dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, datetime, data, strtotime

Estou querendo fazer uma comparação de datas em PHP do tipo: se DataInicio >= DataHoje + 3 dias, faz tal coisa. Senão, não faz nada. Tentei algo assim:

```
if ((1/86400)*(strtotime($_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'])-strtotime(date("d/m/Y"))))>=3) {
   // Do something }
else {
   // Do nothing }
```

Sendo que as duas datas inicialmente estão no formato dd/mm/YYYY. Mas talvez eu possa ter a data de hoje no formato YYYY-mm-dd. Por isso talvez eu tenha de fazer mais de uma conversão de datas. Por exemplo, 23/06/2015 ou 2015-06-23 (hoje) deve ser pelo menos três dias menos que a data da minha SESSION (26/06/2015, por exemplo).

COMO FAÇO?

Comment: A duplicata não me ajudou. Eu posso ter mais de um formato diferente de data e, por isso, mais de uma conversão tenha de ser feita pra diferença de dias.

Comment: [Converter data MySQL (YYYY/mm/dd h:m:s) para dd/mm/aaaa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51692/converter-data-mysql-yyyy-mm-dd-hms-para-dd-mm-aaaa)

Comment: Não, Maicon. Não tem nada de MySQL. E o que deve ser mais fácil é converter a data dd/mm/aaaa para YYYY-mm-dd da Session e aí fazer a diferença.

Comment: Gustavo, ao invés de ler o título das perguntas, leia as respostas.

Comment: Foi mal. Só depois que vi que era um link.

Answer (score -1):

Tens de adicionar mais três dias à data atual para fazeres essa comparação:

```
$data = $_SESSION['buscaReserva']['dataInicio'];
$hoje = date("Y-m-d");

$data = strtotime($data);
$hojeMaisTres = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date . "+3 days"));

if ($data > $hojeMaisTres) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou olhar aqui.

Comment: Conseguiste por isso a trabalhar?

Comment: Não sei se tá dando muito certo. Coloquei no lugar do Do Something e Do Nothing: echo "Correto" e echo "Errado". Mas está sempre dando "Errado". Ou seja, alguma coisa na função ainda não tá certa.