# Trocar formato da data em PHP

Tags: php, data

Estou a tentar trocar o formato da data da seguinte maneira:

```
 public function getDate() {
   $date=$this->date;
   return $date->DATE_FORMAT($date,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p');
}
```

Mas não estou a conseguir ir buscar a data no formato AM e PM.

solução:

```
       public function getDate() {
   $date = new datetime($this->date);
    return $date->format('M d Y h:i A');
}
```

Comment: Qual é o formato que retorna  $this->data ? posta um exemplo.

Comment: Retorna este valor: 2014-09-19 00:32:26                                       Agora queria alterar para formato americano.

Comment: 00 pode ser no formato AM PM ou 24h. Como sabes se está em formato 12h ou 24h?

Comment: Esta usando a função date()/DateTime ou strftime() para formatar?

Comment: dá-me o seguinte erro:  Fatal error: Call to a member function DATE_FORMAT() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prototipo\PHPClasses\Post.php on line 117                                sei k está no formato 24h, pois nos outros exemplos que tenho imprime nesse formato.                                                                         para inserir na BD estou a usar a função now()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A formatação para função [date](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) e a [clase DateTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) ser a seguinte:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
echo $date->format('M d Y h:i A');
```

Saída:

```
Nov 07 2014 03:03 PM
```

Da forma como está com as porcentagens parece que está usando a função [strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php).

Formatações para strftime

```
%b - Mês abreviado (jan-dec)
%d - dia (01-31)
%Y - Ano com quatro digitos (2014)
%h - Mês abreviado conforme o locale (jan-dec)
%i - Hora representada de 01 a 12
%p - Adiciona AM ou PM
```

Equivalente em date

```
M - Mês abreviado (jan-dec)
d - dia (01-31)
Y - Ano com quatro digitos (2014)
? - Não tem é possível formatar a data utlizando locale
h - Hora representada de 01 a 12
A - Adiciona AM ou PM
```

Caso precise formatar a data usando o locale veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8317/91).

Comment: +1 Pois estava aqui desatento não era "a" em vez de "h" mas sim em complemento da formatação.

Comment: Ou um objeto DateInterval que vale uma consideração a ser feita de que [DateInterval::format()](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) não considera o formato **A** como válido.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, a classe DateTime se não me engano usa as mesmasa formatações de date().

Comment: Solução:    public function getDate() {
   $date = new datetime($this->date);
    return $date->format('M d Y h:i A');
}     Muito Obrigado

Comment: @perdeu, a DateTime sim, a DateInterval não. Talvez porque formatação de intervalos não requer uma gama tão grande de formatos, vai entender...

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
public function getDate() {
   $date=$this->date;
   return $date->DATE_FORMAT($date,'%b %d %Y %a:%i %p');
}
```

Confira o exemplo no [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp)

Comment: Rafael, códigos php não são disparados em snippets, somente html, css e js. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2115/apresentando-js-css-e-html-execut%C3%A1veis?cb=1

Comment: A intenção não era ele se tornar um código executável aqui, foi só pra ficar bem formatado, usei de forma errada, vou prestar mais atenção ao postar da próxima vez

Comment: Tranquilo :) . Pra formatar em código basta selecionar o texto e usar o botão `{ }`