# Data em português (pt-br)

Tags: php, data

Tenho o seguinte código em PHP:

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Brazil/East');

$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);

$dia = $datetime->format('d'); 
$mes = $datetime->format('F');
$ano = $datetime->format('Y');

echo $dia . " de " . $mes . " de " . $ano;
?>
```

mas a data vem em inglês:

```
10 de February de 2017
```

como posso ajustar isso ? coloquei um setlocale no inicio do código mas não resolveu...

Comment: Verifica essa solução: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use o `%B` para o formato do mês e como parâmetro do método `date_default_timezone_set()` use `America/Sao_Paulo`. Veja um exemplo simples:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'portuguese'); 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$date = date('Y-m-d');
echo strftime("%d de %B de %Y", strtotime($date));
```

Para ficar registrado, criei um arquivo [DataPorExtensoTimezonePTBR](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/DataPorExtensoTimezonePTBR.php) no GitHub.