# Imprimir dia da semana por extenso somando um dia

Tags: php, data

Estou tentando imprimir o dia da semana por extenso (Segunda, terça...) de uma data retornada do banco de dados.
Porém, sempre está imprimindo com um dia a menos, por exemplo, ao invés de imprimir Segunda, está imprimindo Domingo, queria saber o que posso colocar na linha abaixo para que ele some um dia e, ao invés de exibir 'Domingo', exiba 'Segunda' e assim por diante.

A data está vindo do banco no formato YYYY-DD-MM. Ex: 2017-03-07, nesse caso dia 07/03 é uma terça-feira, mas por algum motivo, está sendo exibido Segunda na hora de imprimir a data.

```
echo JText::sprintf(JHTML::_('date',  $item->data_inicio, JText::_("l, ")));
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar a pergunta um exemplo de data que está tentando?

Comment: Que componente é esse que está utilizando?

Comment: A empresa em que trabalho pagou uma outra empresa para desenvolver o site em Joomla há alguns anos e até hoje estamos tentando corrigir alguns bugs, esse é um exemplo. 
É um componente de agenda que já veio instalado no site.

Comment: Experimente retirar o parametro '1' como argumento do JText().

Comment: [Como fazer a função date formatar uma data em português?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8317/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `date` recebe uma Unix Timestamp, não uma data formatada.

```
// Tranformar YYYY-DD-MM em YYYY-MM-DD
$data_formatada = explode('-', $item->data_inicio);
$data_formatada = join( '-', $data_formatada[0], $data_formatada[2], $data_formatada[1] );

echo JText::sprintf(JHTML::_('date',  strtotime( $data_formatada ), JText::_("l, ")));
```

Comment: Perfeito, agora sim funcionou 100%, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @LeandroSilva veja a alteração, `strtotime` precisa da data em outro formato pra funcionar 100%.

Comment: Massa, por enquanto colocando somente o strtotime está funcionando, depois vou fazer esse esquema de transformar a data de YYYY-DD-MM para YYYY-MM-DD, mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a pergunta já foi respondida, mas para quem precisar pegar o dia da semana em português em sistemas onde não tenha como mudar a língua, pode usar uma função como essa:

```
// Se a variável $minhadataYmdHis não for passada pra função, pega data e hora atual do sistema
function diaSemanaPorExtenso($minhadataYmdHis=0)
{
    if($minhadataYmdHis==0)
    {
        $now = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
        $minhadataYmdHis = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    $diaSemanaN= date("w", strtotime($minhadataYmdHis));

    switch($diaSemanaN)
    {
        case 0:
        $diaSemana="Domingo";
        break;
        case 1:
        $diaSemana="Segunda-feira";
        break;  
        case 2:
        $diaSemana="Ter&ccedil;a-feira";
        break;  
        case 3:
        $diaSemana="Quarta-feira";
        break;
        case 4:
        $diaSemana="Quinta-feira";
        break;  
        case 5:
        $diaSemana="Sexta-feira";
        break;          
        case 6:
        $diaSemana="S&aacute;bado";
        break;              
    }
    return $diaSemana;
}
```

Tirei essa função de uma classe simples para formatação e cálculo de datas que uso e dou manutenção de vez em quando:

DateHelper.php :

http://pastebin.com/WJDbBLF0

Comment: Muito boa solução também, bom saber, conhecimento nunca é demais.