# Compara e substituir indice array

Tags: php, mysql, data, foreach

O problema e o seguinte, estou criando gráfico de OS diárias, só que vem do banco com dia em inglês, gostaria de substituir cada índice pelo valor em português 
Meu código

```
    public function osSemanal($id_company)
{        
    $periodo = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-7 days'));
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("select DAYNAME(dt_chegada) as dia, count(id) as os_gerada from os where id_company= :id_company
    and dt_chegada >= :periodo group by DAYNAME(dt_chegada) order by dt_chegada");
    $sql->bindValue(":id_company", $id_company);
    $sql->bindValue(":periodo", $periodo);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($result as $res):            
        $dados[$res->dia] = $res->os_gerada;
      endforeach;     

    echo json_encode($dados);
}
```

Vem do banco:

```
[0]
"dia"=> "Friday",
"os_gerada"=> 1

[1]
"dia"=> "Sunday",
"os_gerada"=> 4
```

É gerado:

```
"Friday" => 1,
"Sunday" => 4
```

Resultado esperado:

```
"Sexta" => 1,
"Domingo"=> 4
```

Comment: E como você está montando esse `array`?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer a função date() formatar uma data em português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%c3%aas)

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade não vejo como duplicata, pois ele não esta querendo traduzir uma data, na realidade ele quer traduzir uma string que é a chave do array, independente se for dia da semana ou outra palavra.

Comment: De como ele descreveu, é relacionado a data. Mesmo que seja por extenso, ainda é uma data.

Comment: esqueci, postei código, de uma olhada agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`strftime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php) após definir o local:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

echo ucfirst(strftime('%A', strtotime('Monday'))); // Segunda
echo ucfirst(strftime('%A', strtotime('Sunday'))); // Domingo
echo ucfirst(strftime('%A', strtotime('Wednesday'))); // Quarta
echo ucfirst(strftime('%A', strtotime('Friday'))); // Sexta
```

Comment: Mto bom! Vou apagar minha resposta!

Comment: com implementar no meu código, não consegui aqui

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um array com a tradução dos dias da semana, depois percorrer seu array traduzindo a chave dessa maneira:

```
<?php

$arr1 = ['Monday' => 1, 'Tuesday' => 2, 'Wednesday' => 4];
$arrTranslate = ['Monday' => 'Segunda', 'Tuesday' => 'Terça', 'Wednesday' => 'Quarta'];

$newArray = [];
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){

    $newArray[$arrTranslate[$key]] = $value;

}

print_r($newArray);
```

Ou você pode também antes de executar sua consulta chamar outro comando no MySQL que troca o idioma:

`SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';`

Assim seu método ficaria assim:

```
public function osSemanal($id_company)
{
    $periodo = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-7 days'));
    $sqlAux = $this->db->prepare("SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR'");
    $sqlAux->execute();
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("select DAYNAME(dt_chegada) as dia, count(id) as os_gerada from os where id_company= :id_company
    and dt_chegada >= :periodo group by DAYNAME(dt_chegada) order by dt_chegada");
    $sql->bindValue(":id_company", $id_company);
    $sql->bindValue(":periodo", $periodo);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach ($result as $res):
        $dados[$res->dia] = $res->os_gerada;
    endforeach;

    echo json_encode($dados);
}
```

Comment: ` foreach ($result as $res):            
            $dados[$res->dia] = $res->os_gerada;
          endforeach;                         
          $arrTranslate = ['Monday' => 'Segunda', 'Tuesday' => 'Terça', 'Wednesday' => 'Quarta','Thursday'=>'Quinta','Friday'=>'Sexta',
          'Saturday'=>'Sabado','Sunday'=>'Domingo'];          
          $newArray = [];
          foreach($dados as $key => $value){          
              $newArray[$arrTranslate[$key]] = $value;          
          }       `

Comment: ficou melhor assim, e um foreach a menos kkk, vlw

Comment: pois é @JuniorRamoty, quando respondi a primeira vez, não tinha o exemplo da Query, achei que o array poderia estar vindo de algum plugin, então respondi atendendo a necessidade do momento. ai quando postou o resto do código ficou mais claro.

Comment: eu intendi, vlw

Answer (score 0):

Você pode traduzir os dias da semana com Switch ou com o IF exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
$DIA_en = array();
// Armazenar os dias da semana em uma array
$DIA_en['DIA'] = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');
for($x = 0; $x <= count($DIA_en['DIA']); $x++) {
    if( $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] == "Monday" ) {
        echo "Antes: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<br>";
        $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] = "Segunda";
        echo "Depois: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<hr>";
    } else if ( $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] == "Tuesday" ) {
        echo "Antes: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<br>";
        $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] = "Terça";
        echo "Depois: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<hr>";
    } else if ( $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] == "Wednesday" ) {
        echo "Antes: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<br>";
        $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] = "Quarta";
        echo "Depois: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<hr>";
    } else if ( $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] == "Thursday" ) {
        echo "Antes: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<br>";
        $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] = "Quinta";
        echo "Depois: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<hr>";
    } else if ( $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] == "Friday" ) {
        echo "Antes: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<br>";
        $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] = "Sexta";
        echo "Depois: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<hr>";
    } else if ( $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] == "Saturday" ) {
        echo "Antes: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<br>";
        $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] = "Sábado";
        echo "Depois: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<hr>";
    } else if ( $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] == "Sunday" ) {
        echo "Antes: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<br>";
        $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] = "Domingo";
        echo "Depois: " . $DIA_en['DIA'][$x] . "<hr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Retornará:

Antes: Monday

Depois: Segunda

Antes: Tuesday

Depois: Terça

Antes: Wednesday

Depois: Quarta

Antes: Thursday

Depois: Quinta

Antes: Friday

Depois: Sexta

Antes: Saturday

Depois: Sábado

Antes: Sunday

Depois: Domingo

Comment: Considere responder na necessidade da pergunta, ele quer a tradução dos índices do array onde sua resposta não se aplica.