# PHP - Função de Data

Tags: php

EU criei esta função de data para mostrar a data, dia e més.

O problema é que mostra o més em Ingles..

```
exemplo: March, 10, 2018".
```

Como faço para que ele leia em Português?

```
function dateName($date) {

    $result = "";

    $convert_date = strtotime($date);
    $month = date('F',$convert_date);
    $year = date('Y',$convert_date);
    $name_day = date('l',$convert_date);
    $day = date('j',$convert_date);


    $result = $month . " " . $day . ", " . $year;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Apenas para contribuir um pouco, pesquise sobre o Carbon, ele resolve isso muito bem. Não estou dizendo USE, estou dizendo para conhecer a ferramenta e de repente pegar ideias lendo o codigo fonte.

Comment: Por vezes não chego a entender, se isto é para ajudar ou apenas mais um Forum sem resposta.

Comment: Sua resposta esta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: Ate podia estar ali, mas como insiro isso no codigo...estou confuso..

Comment: Tente inserir isso no inicio da sua função: `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');`