# Problemas ao exibir data em formato apropriado

Tags: php

tenho esta data:

`<?php echo date("d/M/Y", strtotime($registro['DATA_VENCIMENTO'])); ?>`

está exibindo assim: `15/Oct/2019`

Como faço para exibir em português,sem perder a formatação que coloquei (d/M/Y)?

quero exibir assim: `15/10/2019`

Comment: tenta com setlocale (LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: Eles explicam como fazer mas fica data por extenso, eu nao posso perder a formatação

Comment: Ah, você alterou a pergunta... Ao invés de `d/M/Y`, faça `d/m/Y`, com o `m` minúsculo. Tem todas as formatações possíveis na documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Comment: Obrigado! Anderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php), a formatação `M` é uma representação **textual** curta do nome do mês (três letras); por sua vez, a formatação `m` é a representação **numérica** do mês, com zero a esquerda.

Então basta trocar `M` por `m`:

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($registro['DATA_VENCIMENTO']));
```