# Problema com setlocale no servidor web

Tags: php, data

Estou com um site online que esta setado o time zone para America/Sao_Paulo e utilizando setlocale para portugues, mas mesmo assim o site onde tenho funções strtime, dão os texto em inglês,  tentei colocar no código a função set time zone mas ainda assim não funcionou.
Alguém consegue me ajudar. Não sei se é algum problema comum ou não, ps: no phpinfo() esta setado para são paulo.

Comment: a data é exibida apenas com números? ex: 14/03/2019

Comment: não são exibidas os textos em ingles, como ex(Thursday)

Comment: Se não me engano, `date` sempre retorna os textos em inglês. O timezone só serve para saber qual a data e hora atual a ser considerada (já que isso varia conforme o fuso horário), e o idioma não tem nada a ver com o timezone. Se quer textos em outro idioma, use [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) junto com [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: estou utilziando este setlocale setlocale {(LC_TIME, "portuguese-brazilian");} mesmo assim o strtime ignora

Comment: Não sei se o PHP reconhece "portuguese-brazilian", tem que ser "pt_BR". Veja também se o locale está instalado no servidor: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10909911

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer a função date() formatar uma data em português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%c3%aas)

Comment: Irei ver se esta instalado, mas o "portuguese-brazilian" funciona, por que pelo menos no localhost ele reconhece, so estou com este problema nos servidor de hospedagem

Comment: @LipESprY não é duplicada, olhei mas não é este este problema

Comment: Resolvido, o servidor nao aceita portuguese-brazilian, mesmo no manual do php costando que aceita

Comment: Na verdade `setlocale` retorna `false` quando o locale não é reconhecido (e se não me engano, não mostra nenhuma mensagem de erro). E aí o locale não é alterado e ele usa o que já estava configurado antes (e no localhost provavelmente estava português, e no servidor inglês). Verifique o retorno de `setlocale` só pra ter certeza... E [no manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#117529) só vi que aceita `Portuguese_Brazilian`, mas só no Windows, nos demais sistemas é pt_BR mesmo

Answer (score 1):

> "*- o servidor nao aceita portuguese-brazilian, mesmo no manual do php costando que aceita*"

Feitas algumas pesquisas sobre o `setlocale`, posso concluir que ele não tem ligação direta ao `timezone` ou a versão do seu servidor PHP. Mas ele é diretamente dependente do sistema operacional em que está rodando seu servidor PHP!

Como exemplo, meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, com Windows 10 e rodando o PHP através do [UniServer Zero XIII](https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/), trouxe os seguintes resultados:

```
// locale string atual:
echo setlocale(LC_TIME, 0); // C
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); // LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'portuguese-brazilian');
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y'); // domingo, 17 de mar�o de 2019

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'portuguese-brazilian.utf8');
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y'); // domingo, 17 de março de 2019

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y'); // domingo, 17 de março de 2019

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8');
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y'); // domingo, 17 de março de 2019

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1');
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y'); // Sunday, 17 de March de 2019

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'portuguese');
echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y'); // domingo, 17 de mar�o de 2019
```

- <sub>Obs.: teste uma por vez, já que ele considera a última válida caso não encontre!</sub>
- <sub>Charset do HTML: utf8</sub>

---

A própria documentação do PHP recomenda que os usuários de Windows busque a ***string do local (string locale)*** no [site da Microsoft MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/39cwe7zf(v=vs.90)):

> **Dica** Usuários do windows encontraram informações úteis sobre as strings de locale no site MSDN da Microsoft. Strings das línguas suportadas podem ser encontradas [» aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as strings de pais/região suportados [»  aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Sistemas windows suportam códigos de três letras para pais/região especificados por ISO 3166-Alpha-3, que pode ser encontrada em Unicode website. - [PHP: setlocale](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php)

Mas achei mais conveniente através da [Tabela de locais do site Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales). Que já adianta: não há forma de adicionar novos locais no Windows. Já no Linux é possível instalar novos locais e algumas distribuições já tem todas por padrão. O Moodle, inclusive, explica isso.

Outra questão é que você pode definir várias *locale strings* de uma só vez e o PHP se encarrega de definir "a que encontrar primeiro".

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese", ...);
```

<sub>Obs.: isso não quer dizer que ele vai definir a melhor!</sub>

Outra recomendação é, se viável, sempre voltar ao padrão depois de exibir sua data com o idioma em questão. Isso vai prevenir possíveis incompatibilidades relacionadas a várias outras funções do PHP. Vide relatos nas *User Contributed Notes* na [documentação do setlocale](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php).

No geral, se você tiver acesso root ao seu servidor, não vai ser difícil encontrar uma opção válida. Caso não tenha, terá de se render ao suporte da empresa que hospeda seu site - que nem sempre atende as expectativas<strike>, onde tudo que eles não querem fazer é transformado em "viola a política de segurança"</strike>.