# EXIBIR DATA POR EXTENSO PHP

Tags: php, java, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Galera, seguinte.. tenho uma pagina de impressão de contrato onde preciso converter a data do campo por extenso

```
<?php echo $result->estado?> - <?php echo $result->data_contrato?>
```

No campo "data_contrato" é exibido desta forma "10/10/2019"...

Como faço pra exibir por extenso?

Quero exibir "10 de Outubro de 2019"

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs

Comment: mas eu nao quero pegar data de hoje, preciso pegar a data de dentro do campo do banco de dados mysql...

Comment: Independente de onde pega a data, a solução é a mesma do link fornecido pelo @MarcosXavier (inclusive, o formato data do MySQL independe da formatação de tela)

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo:

```html
//Criar a conexão com banco de dados, colocando as credencias do seu banco de dados
$conn = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario_banco_dados", "senha_banco_dados", "nome_banco_dados");

//Define informações locais 
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

//Pesquisar as datas no banco de dados
$query_artigos = "SELECT * FROM artigos";
$result_artigos = mysqli_query($conn, $query_artigos);
//Ler o resultado obtido do banco de dados
while($row_artigo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_artigos)){
 echo "Id do artigo: " . $row_artigo['id'] . "";
 //Imprimir a data conforme está no banco de dados
 echo "Data no formato salvo no banco de dados: " . $row_artigo['data'] . "";
 //Converter a data para o formato brasileiro
 echo "Data no formato salvo no banco de dados: " . date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row_artigo['data'])) . "";
 //Converte a data por extenso
 echo "Data por extenso: " . strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime($row_artigo['data'])) . "";
}
```