# Quando troco de strftime() para date() volta escrever em inglês

Tags: php

tenho uma variável que trago do banco que é date (não datetime) no seguinte formato:

```
echo $data; // me retorna: 2022-06-20
```

Eu preciso pegar o nome do mês da variável, e quando uso a função `strftime` vem certinho, me retorna “junho” (o que me faz pensar que o locale já está pt-BR), mas o `strftime` já está obsoleto no PHP, portanto troquei isso:

```
strftime('%B', strtotime($data));
```

Para isso:

```
date("F", strtotime($data));
```

E quando faço isso o mês fica como “june”, em inglês. Como posso fazer com que ele continue vindo em português?

Comment: Você pode tentar usar IntlDateFormatter se tiver a extensão Intll ativada. Veja se estas respostas te ajudam https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8317/como-fazer-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-formatar-uma-data-em-portugu%C3%AAs e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172415/generate-appropriate-pattern-for-intldateformatter-format-based-on-locale-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estudando sua pergunta e o comentário que sugeriu a utilização de `IntlDateFormatter`, cheguei ao seguinte resultado:

```
//data recuperada do banco de dados no formato iso
$data_recuperada_do_banco = '2022-06-20';

//convertendo a data recuperada em DateTime
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data_recuperada_do_banco);

//inicializando IntlDateFormatter
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('pt_BR', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'America/Sao_Paulo', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'MMMM');

//convertendo e mostrando o mês traduzido para pt_BR
echo $fmt->format($data);
```

Mais detalhes sobre [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intldateformatter.create.php) e [**sintaxe do formato data/hora**](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax).

Para que isso funcione a extensão **intl** precisa estar ativada no **php.ini**, caso contrário você provavelmente receberá uma mensagem de erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found in [...]
```

Caso não tenha acesso ao **php.ini**, pode optar por uma função personalizada, algo como:

```
/**
 * Retorna o mês inerente à data injetada em português
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @return string 
 */
function getMonthBR(string $data)
{                 
    switch ( date('M', strtotime($data) ) ) 
    {
        case 'Jan':
            return 'Janeiro';

        case 'Feb':
            return 'Fevereiro';

        case 'Mar':
            return 'Março';

        case 'Apr':
            return 'Abril';

        case 'May':
            return 'Maio';

        case 'Jun':
            return 'Junho';

        case 'Jul':
            return 'Julho';

        case 'Aug':
            return 'Agosto';

        case 'Sep':
            return 'Setembro';

        case 'Oct':
            return 'Outubro';

        case 'Nov':
            return 'Novembro';

        case 'Dec':
            return 'Dezembro';
    }

}
```

Depois é só chamar a função passando a data no formato iso:

```
//chamando a função e injetando a data_recuperada_do_banco_no_formato_iso
echo getMonthBR($data_recuperada_do_banco);
```

**Resultado final:**

```
Data recuperada do banco: 2022-06-20<br> 
Resultado com <kbd>IntlDateFormatter("2022-06-20")</kbd>: junho<br> 
Resultado com <kbd>getMonthBR("2022-06-20")</kbd>: Junho<br>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Freba.